# Servlet doFilter setAttributes not available in Servlet

Tags: servlets, attributes, jstl, servlet-filters

I'm trying to add an Attribute to the request via `doFilter` before passing it to the Servlet, so that a value in JSTL will be set. I simply do `req.setAttribute("b", "blah")` in the filter, but it doesn't seem to get set in the JSTL file. How would I do this?

Comment: Please supply the relevant filter code and JSP fragment,

Comment: You are doing it right.  Set the attribute on the request and use it on the jsp via jstl.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to pinpoint the root cause without seeing the code. There are several possible causes.

- You're sending a redirect after setting the attribute instead of continuing with the same request.
- You're accessing the attribute with the wrong name (case sensitive!).
- You're accessing the attribute the wrong way.
- The attribute is been overridden somewhere further down in the request processing.
- There's a page scoped attribute with the same name which has no value.
- You're misinterpreting the results.
- Etc.

By the way, there's no such thing as a "JSTL file". Perhaps you meant "JSP file".

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the `doFilter` method uses `ServletRequest` instead of `HttpServletRequest` which is the one that has the `setAttribute` method.  Most of my filters are something like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, 
                     ServletResponse servletResponse, 
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;                                                                      

    // do what you must...

    chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

}
```

Comment: I think OP is saying they're doing a `req.setAttribute()` but that the attribute isn't present in the JSP file; not sure how this addresses that.

Comment: This is nonsense. Casting doesn't change the object itself, but just the type of the reference. Method calls doesn't behave differently.

Comment: @BalusC my first read of the question pointed out to not being able to use `request.setAttribute` which would happen if no casting was done.

Comment: That would only end up in uncompilable code, not in missing attribute in request scope.